# Google Apps Script getting the value of a file selected from <input ref="image1" type="file" name="image1" id="img"> in a Vue3 dialog

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, google-apps-script, camera

Hello I have a Google Apps Script with a Vue3 dialog where I'm trying to implement a button the user can press that will activate their camera.
I have the following working and on a mobile device. The command   launches and asks the user if they want to select from their photo library, take a picture of upload a file.

Once I upload a file or take a picture, I can't seem to get the value of image1 or image2, that is the filename.
Once the user presses "Save", I want to then copy the selected files onto a google drive. However, the save() function states that image1 is undefined.

If there is a better way to doing this, I'm very interested. I have a data form and I'm trying to add the ability to take a few pictures during the data entry. This is what I need, I just can't get the value of the images selected/opened.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
    Vue dialog
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="800px">
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <span class="text-h5">{{ formTitle }}</span>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-container>

           <input ref="image1" type="file" name="image1" id="img">
           <input ref="image2" type="file" name="image2" id="img">

      </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn color="blue-darken-1"  variant="outlined"   @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
      <v-btn color="blue-darken-1"  variant="elevated"  @click="save"   >Save</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>


<script>
// Save the record and open the email dialog
  save() {

  const imageFile1 = image1
  console.log("Image #1:" + imageFile1);
}
</script>
```